# Is it recommended to invoke REST-API through microservice?

Tags: rest, web-services, microservices

Is it recommended to invoke REST-API through microservice instead of direct REST endpoint calling? any pros & cons on that? is it a kind of duplication (redundancy).? 
for example, We are using API Management Gateway. There are so many REST API's which are providing for UI/API related functions. but if our client trying to use those APIs through their microservices then it would be a kind of duplicate scenario, or not.?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please explain what is the difference in your case between ```REST-API through microservice```  and ```direct REST endpoint calling``` ? - Please edit your question to add extra details.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny
Thanks for ur input, I have changed the body of the question again

Comment: I think some more info is still needed :| Do you mean calling the controller/action methods directly instead of going via making a web request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have microservices if it is not needed. You should start by reading more about microservices. It really depends on your project. There should be no difference in calling an endpoint whether you have a monolith architecture or a microservice. My advice would be to read more about microservices.

I hope you will find a way with the challenge you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I can understand is , you are trying to ask if you can use same api which can be called from UI as well as your client will call it from their microservice.
If this is so , then there are generally no pros and cons as such. It all depends on how your architecture is designed. 
If you are using same api for both i.e. UI as well as you are exposing to your client , then probably your api design is very flexible, but at the same time are you handling security properly ?
In other case say you are using different apis, then yes it would be a redundancy lets say if input/output params are same in both cases.
So you really need to understand the design first.